# Несколько данных в 1 значении массива

Tags: javascript, массивы

Подскажите возможно ли такое:

вместо цифры 30 поставить несколько значений только для объекта val1?

```
 {
   name:"название", 
   val1:30,
   val2:'',
   val3:true,
   val4:false,
   val5:false,
   val6:false,
 },
```

Answer (score 2):

Массив?

```
{
   name:"название",
   val1:[30,31,32,33],
   val2:'',
   val3:true,
   val4:false,
   val5:false,
   val6:false,
}
```

Comment: ДА, спасибо, не подскажете, как изменить val1 в строке ниже, что бы он брал любое значение из массива?

        filter.push(document.getElementById('val1').options[document.getElementById('val1').selectedIndex].value);

Comment: @нгш, не понял суть вопроса. Кто должен брать любое значение из массива?

Comment: Смотрите, есть фильтр, и там есть такая строка:

filter.push(document.getElementById('val1').options[document.getElementById('val1').selectedIndex].value);

Эта страка берёт значение val как раз из массива над которым я сейчас химичу. Как только я меняю значение val1 как вы мне показали, фильтр перестаёт работать, я виню стоку указанную выше, а точнее как она берёт данные, как я только не пытался их изменить:

myvar[0]['vaal1'] и myvar[0]['vaal1'].value

в общем что не подставлял вместо val1 код перестаёт работать

Comment: @нгш, можете весь код предоставить?

Comment: @artem328 http://jsfiddle.net/3Pt34/3/